# Office Automation - Create msg file

Tags: python, flask, winapi, outlook, com

I'm trying to create an Outlook Message File (.msg) file using Python, specifically from Flask.

Here's what I have:

```
import win32com.client
def html2msg():
    com_object = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
    com_file = com_object.CreateItem(0)
    com_file.Subject = 'Subject'
    com_file.HTMLBody = '<html><head></head><body><p>Test Email</p></body></html>'
    com_file.SaveAs('new.msg')
    com_file.Close(0)
```

This works fine when run as a user in Windows, or instigated from within flask when the flask app is run manually as a user...

The issue comes when it is run behind `IIS` with `wfastcgi`: I get this non-specific error:

```
File "<COMObject Outlook.Application>", line 2, in CreateItem
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467260, 'Operation aborted', None, None)
```

I previously had similar(ish) issues with Word, which were caused because the com object was being run under the system profile, and were solved by creating a folder as per: https://theether.net/kb/100120?id=100120

Has anyone managed to accomplish something similar?

Comment: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue comes when it is run behind IIS with wfastcgi: I get this non-specific error:

The [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article states the following for the error you've got:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.
>
> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

As a workaround, you need to use a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI or just any wrapper around that API such as Redemption.

If you deal with Exchange server profiles only, consider using EWS, see [Start using web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/start-using-web-services-in-exchange) for more information.

Comment: Thanks,  I got fairly far along with Redemption based on your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be compatible with Server 2019. It threw an error: pywintypes.com_error: (-2147220998, 'Wrong OS or OS version for application', None, None). Any other wrapper that you'd recommend?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the Redemption developer?

Comment: You may consider using EWS.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I ended up using MsgKit: https://github.com/Sicos1977/MsgKit.